# Which usage of the below sentence is right?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

Was writing a text for a post. But was not sure what was the right way to put it.

> 1. Bajaj​ **serving** Backbone support to run the first ever online
>      competition by Microsoft​.
> 2. Bajaj​ **serves** Backbone support to run the first ever online
>        competition by Microsoft​.
> 3. Bajaj​​ **is serving** Backbone support to run the first ever online
>      competition by Microsoft​.

Comment: *Serve support* doesn't make English sense. Who is Bajaj, and what exactly is it Bajaj does with Backbone? And does Backbone 'run' the competition, or does it merely support running it?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about backbone.js, 3 sounds fine. If it's a different backbone, we need some more context. The sentence might need some more adjustment- is Microsoft running the competition? That seems likely, but the sentence is a little unclear. Again, more context would help.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, 1 is not a sentence, but a phrase (perhaps a clause) as in "Bajaj​; serving **as** Backbone support to run the first ever online competition by Microsoft​; also coordinates several other support services".

3 is the correct sentence, though I would also add the word "as" after "serving". Without the word "as" the sentence implies that Bajaj is a servant and Backbone is a master.

However I would rewrite the whole sentence to this: "Bajaj​​ is providing support services for Backbone for Microsoft's **first-ever** online competition.

Lasty, is Backbone: Backbone.js? Unless the audience knows what this is, I might clarify this as well.  Is the support for programming or for others using it? Or is it hardware support to help it function? Or is it some other type of support?

Answer (score 0):

1 is incorrect.

2 and 3 are almost correct, but I believe you need an 'as' after serves/serving. Serve as a *transitive verb* (without the as) has meanings including preparing and presenting food and services, or to work for a government term or military service. Serve as an *intransitive verb* (with the as) means to be of a specific use, that use being "backbone support" in this case. I believe the latter is what you want.

I am also unsure why backbone is capitalized. Unless it's a specific technology I am not aware of, I do not think it should be capitalized?

source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/serve

**Edit:** assuming Backbone is the library for which Bajaj (a person) is providing help, the sentence should go like this: "Bajaj is providing Backbone support for the first ever online competition run by Microsoft". I do not believe 'serve' is the most appropriate verb in this case.

Comment: It is a JavaScript program thingy. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js